# Can an Ajax POST request be altered by a user via the browser before it is sent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Please forgive me if this is a stupid question but I can't seem to find a straight answer to this.

For example...

1) The Ajax `data` in this function that is going to be sent is already populated server side, with PHP, when the user lands on the page.

```
 url: "http://somewebsite.com/api",
 dataType: "json",
 method: "POST",
 cache: false,
    data : {
            "action": "test",
            "userid": "1234",
            "amount": "20"
           },
 .......
```

2) The user then clicks a button to invoke the function that fires this `POST` request

By using Chrome or Firefox developer tools, is there anyway for the user to alter the `action`, `id` or `amount` variables before they click the button, thereby changing the data before the request is fired?

I've seen a lot of comments like "anybody can manipulate POST data in the browser if they want to" but I can't find any information about how this would be done, IF it could be done in the given example.

Comment: You can edit the sources (Chrome dev tools) or I think it's called scripts (Firefox Firebug) prior to invoking the ajax request

Comment: Perhaps [this post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests) is relevant.

Comment: So the answer is yes then! So basically Ajax used without any kind of security token system is basically completely insecure?

Comment: @user3717922 - if security is an issue, then use security devices (like tokens) - though, tokens aren't going to stop other data (data not set by the server) being changed by a malicious user

Comment: Wow, I didn't realise the dev tools were that deep. So how would it be possible for anybody to send a variable reliably from a webpage to a server using Ajax when they don't know what that variable is going to be?

Comment: by use of secure tokens (JWT for example)

Comment: If it is a case of having to use tokens, could somebody please point me in the direction of a page or post that explains how to set this up with Ajax requests?

Comment: see where I said, "JWT for example" try searching for "jwt"

Comment: Even with tokens someone can intercept request and modify it by running simple code in dev tools console. jQuery  makes it really easy by using `ajaxSend()` https://jsfiddle.net/jykokeh7/ which allows you to modify request before it is sent

Comment: So you're saying that even with using tokens Ajax is pretty much useless for sending any kind of data that you need to rely on?

Comment: No not useless at all. As with anything that is sent to your server you must always validate it server side before processing it. Never ever trust any user input regardless of how it is sent

Comment: But surely if tokens can be intercepted and altered (just read about a big security flaw in JWT), how can you ever trust anything coming from Ajax when the receiving server never knows what the data is going to be beforehand? Example : Server 1 generates a random number between 1-999. A user intercepts that and changes it. Server 2 is just expecting an int between 1-999 but will never know if Server 1 generated that number or the user intercepted it and chose their own.

Comment: Now using PHP Server 1 could send Server 2 the random int using another secure method that isn't at all exposed to the user before the Ajax request is fired, Server 2 stores the variable somewhere and then validates that against the incoming Ajax request, but that just seems like a massive waste of time and resources, not to mention repetition when it should all be possible with Ajax alone.

Comment: Yep, JWT is not a route I'm going to use. How to exploit a JWT Token... https://blog.websecurify.com/2017/02/hacking-json-web-tokens.html